# Java String Manipulation - substring

Tags: java, string

I want to be able to take a String that has this specific form:

> R = ( abc ) i + ( def ) j + ( ghi ) k

and take each panthesis and store its content in another String, so the output would be something like S1 = "abc", S2 = "def", S3 = "ghi". The problem is that after trimming the String and looking for the first parenthesis to create a substring starting from that position I get an error message that the parenthesis is at position - 1. The code I' ve used is :

```
        S1 = equation.substring( equation.indexOf( "(" ) );
```

What could be wrong and how would you suggest me to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 if it did not find the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using StringTokenizer it easier to split strings with it.
You can

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(R,"(");
String S1 = st.nextToken();
String S2 = st.nextToken();
String S3 = st.nextToken();
```

This would split the R string from using the delimeter (;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the use of `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`, specifically the method `substringBetween`

```
public static String[] substringsBetween(String str,
                                         String open,
                                         String close)
```

Example:

```
String[] result = StringUtils.substringsBetween("(a)(b)(c)", "(", ")")
//= ["a","b","c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are after, you might use a *regular expression* and compile a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to build a `List` of `tokens`. Below, `\\(` and `\\)` represent *literal* characters. Then `\\s*` matches (optional) white space. Finally, group any consecutive characters with `\\w+`. Like,

```
String str = "R = ( abc ) i + ( def ) j + ( ghi ) k";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    tokens.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Which will populate `tokens` with

```
[abc, def, ghi]
```

as desired. Using a dynamic data structure like `List` means your solution can handle more (or fewer) matching expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Could use regex, Java has support for this through `java.util.regex.Pattern` class. Note: I answered at same time as another regex answer. This answer only deals with the simple case of matching anything between the brackets.

```
String input = "R = ( abc ) i + ( def ) j + ( ghi ) k";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
abc 
def 
ghi
```